# How do I filter out SELECT results from tables?

Tags: sql

I have three tables that have user name/id and how many tasks they have submitted. I'm trying to SELECT user.name and the max amount of submissions they have for a single task.

```
SELECT DISTINCT O.nimi, COUNT(T.id)
FROM Opiskelijat O
LEFT JOIN Lahetykset L  ON O.id = L.opiskelija_id
LEFT JOIN Tehtavat T ON T.id = L.tehtava_id
GROUP BY O.id, L.tehtava_id
```

[image]

[image]

The first picture shows the tables in question. In the second picture the above is what I'm trying to get, and the bottom is what my code does at the moment. I'm trying to get it to only show Maija - 3 instead of both.

Comment: 1) You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, except those who are arguments to set functions. I.e. try GROUP BY O.nimi.

Comment: 2) You rarely never combine `GROUP BY` with `SELECT DISTINCT`, because the GROUP BY itself eliminates duplicates.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and the expected result as formatted text, not images or links to images.

Comment: If I group by O.nimi, it doesn't work as intended. The results have to be grouped by user id, not name.

Comment: @Tuck . . . Please explain the logic you want implemented.  Your question is not clear.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Did you look at the picture I attached? In the bottom most picture is what my code currently does. I don't want there to be two instances of Maija, only one with Maija - 3, as 3 is the highest numerical value associated with her.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe somehing like this:

```
SELECT O.nimi, COUNT(*)
FROM Opiskelijat O
LEFT JOIN Lahetykset L  ON O.id = L.opiskelija_id
LEFT JOIN Tehtavat T ON T.id = L.tehtava_id
GROUP BY O.id, O.nimi
```

As was pointed out, you need to have all the selected output fields in the GROUP BY. And also the DISTINCT should not be needed. I think the problem was the group by on L.tehtava_id.

Comment: That doesn't work. Why do I need to have all the selected output fields in the GROUP BY?

Answer (score 0):

If you want one row per `nimi` that should be the only column in the `GROUP BY`.  I think you want:

```
SELECT O.nimi, COUNT(T.id)
FROM Opiskelijat O LEFT JOIN
     Lahetykset L
     ON O.id = L.opiskelija_id LEFT JOIN
     Tehtavat T
     ON T.id = L.tehtava_id
GROUP BY O.nimi;
```

I suspect that you don't actually need the join to `Tehtavat`:

```
SELECT O.nimi, COUNT(L.tehtava_id)
FROM Opiskelijat O LEFT JOIN
     Lahetykset L
     ON O.id = L.opiskelija_id 
GROUP BY O.nimi;
```

Comment: This doesn't work. If I group by nimi, they are ordered alphabetically so in wrong order and the numbers are wrong because it sums up all the different name+task combinations.

Comment: @Tuck: if you want a different sort order, then change it by adding an `order by`

Comment: This still sums up the numbers together... In the example picture, it would show Maija 4 when it should show Maija 3

Comment: @Tuck You need two levels of aggregation - first (count) by Tehtavat and Opiskelijat and second (max) by Opiskelijat.